# Cloud ML Engine online prediction not scaling

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I have created a Cloud ML model that serves online predictions. The model is a simple classification model based on retraining inception v3. I require my model to process many instances (cropped images in my case) in each request. The request body is formatted as follows:

```
instances = []

count = 0
for item in itemMap:

    w = itemMap[item]['width']
    h = itemMap[item]['height']

    x1 = itemMap[item]['x']
    y1 = itemMap[item]['y']
    x2 = x1 + w
    y2 = y1 + h

    crop_x1 = int(x1-w/2)
    crop_x2 = int(x2+w/2)
    crop_y1 = int(y1-h/5)
    crop_y2 = int(y2+h/5)

    #cropped and resized image 
    cropped_image = frame.crop((crop_x1,crop_y1,crop_x2,crop_y2)) 
    resized_crop = cropped_image.resize((299,299))

    buffer = BytesIO()
    resized_crop.save(buffer, format="JPEG")
    img_str = base64.b64encode(buffer.getvalue())

    instances.append({"key":str(count), "image_bytes": {"b64": img_str.decode('utf-8')}})

    count += 1
```

Here are the key parts on my request code:

```
def predict_json(project, model, instances, version=None):
    """Send json data to a deployed model for prediction.

    Args:
        project (str): project where the Cloud ML Engine Model is deployed.
        model (str): model name.
        instances ([Mapping[str: Any]]): Keys should be the names of Tensors
            your deployed model expects as inputs. Values should be datatypes
            convertible to Tensors, or (potentially nested) lists of datatypes
            convertible to tensors.
        version: str, version of the model to target.
    Returns:
        Mapping[str: any]: dictionary of prediction results defined by the
            model.
    """
    # Create the ML Engine service object.
    # To authenticate set the environment variable
    # GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=<path_to_service_account_file>
    service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('ml', 'v1')
    name = 'projects/{}/models/{}'.format(project, model)

    if version is not None:
        name += '/versions/{}'.format(version)

    response = service.projects().predict(
        name=name,
        body={'instances': instances}
    ).execute()

    if 'error' in response:
        raise RuntimeError(response['error'])

    return response['predictions']
```

and:

```
Map = []

t = time.time()
chunk = instances[0:50]
Mapping = predict_json(project, model, chunk)
Map.extend(Mapping)

elapsed = time.time() - t
print(elapsed)
```

The model works but is not scaling. The time takes to send the request and receive a response is near linear.

1 instance: 1.1077377796173096 s, 
2 instances: 1.763524055480957 s, 
10 instances: 8.115557432174683 s, 
50 instances: 44.36078429222107 s,

Any more than 50 instances and I get a time out, meaning that I have to do requests in chunks.

I want Cloud ML to scale the nodes so that the request time is near flat (one node for each instance). I have tried sending many requests one after another to see if Cloud-Ml will allocate more nodes. I also do not want to use batch prediction as the response must come in real time.

How do I get Cloud-ML to scale the requests and reduce my inference time?

Update (07/12/2018): I have also tried creating a version with minNodes: 5 and there was no change in request times.

Comment: did my answer help?

Answer (score 4):

When you have more than one data instance that needs processing, you have two options:

1. Send a single request containing all of the instances (a batch).
2. Send a separate request out for each instance individually (usually in parallel).

There are pros and cons to both. The first option (send them all in the same request) is the most efficient, i.e., the cost per prediction and the time per prediction is lowest. However, the wall clock time for the predictions will be higher. For example, you may send 50 images and it might take 50 seconds process those. So the time per image is 1 second and the cost is 50 node*seconds.

**You should especially know that each instance in a request is processed on the same machine -- which is why you are observing no horizontal scaling.**

On the other hand, if you create a new thread for each image and send one image per request, thus sending out the requests in parallel, you may get all of the responses back within, say, 10 seconds (firing a large number of requests simultaneously can cause new servers to spin up which can add to the processing time). The average time per request might be 2.5 seconds and you might require 25 machines to process it all (costing 25*2.5 = 62.5 node*seconds)

So the wall clock time is lower, but the time per prediction and the cost are higher. It's a tradeoff each project will make based on their individual needs.

For your use case, it's clear you're expecting horizontal scaling, so I recommend 
sending fewer images per request, and more requests in parallel, keeping in mind the above tradeoffs. If you fire too many requests off simultaneously, you may cause more machines to spin up to handle the load, which will add to the processing time, so you'll want to balance how many images you put in a request and how many 'min_nodes' you keep up.

Finally, you can consider using the [batch prediction service](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/batch-predict) which is very efficient at processing (large amounts of) data in parallel. However, that service is intended for a fairly large number of input instances and has fairly large startup time (around 5 minutes). The file in/file out interface is also not always the best interface for every project.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Robbie. 
As suggested, I've tried multiple-parallel calls for online predictions (50 inputs in parallel); I keep getting network-traffic error 429 - "Rate of traffic exceeds capacity of target model"; [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/troubleshooting#http_status_codes) suggests the use of exponential backoff, but I couldn't find any examples on how to do it. Any suggestions? 
PS: I face traffic error when number of files exceed around 25-26. Anything more, error pops for at least a couple of files and results do not get populated.

Comment: Here's some general info about exponential backoff [1] and here's a library you might try (I've not used it myself): [2]

[1]: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/exponential-backoff
[2]: https://pypi.org/project/retrying/

Comment: Alternatively, if you know ahead of time that you're going to send a lot of traffic, you can actually update the `min_nodes` parameter on your model *before* sending the traffic, and then reset once you are done. You'll want to be careful with your code that runs "when you're done" to be very robust because you don't want to leave too many nodes up for too long.

Comment: The latter is what we've thought of using as a work-around. Thanks for the references. Facing a different issue now. I have to send in large float32 arrays as input for my online preds, exceeding the payload limit even with base64 encoding. So I'm compressing using zlib, then base64-encoding and sending the JSON. Any suggestions on how to decode the base64 and decompress on TensorFlow's end in the serving function? Or do you think there's a better option to try?

Comment: Did you ever get around this? I'm facing the exact same issue, where I fire 10 parallel requests and they take exactly the same time as firing one single request with 10 samples of input data.

On another note, I also had the same problem you did (i.e., payload limit exceeding), which I worked around by sending an URL which contained the data required. The inference script then downloads the data as a first step, and then processes it. Of course, you need to be able to set the data visible somewhere, or perhaps even within a GCS bucket.

Answer (score 1):

The [relevant documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/prediction-overview#understanding_prediction_nodes_and_resource_allocation) outlines the scaling behavior for serving predictions. Specifically, the section on online prediction should tell you what you need to know:

> The online prediction service scales the number of nodes it uses, to maximize the number of requests it can handle without introducing too much latency. To do that, the service:
>
> - Allocates some nodes the first time you request predictions after a long pause in requests.
> - Scales the number of nodes in response to request traffic, adding nodes when traffic increases, and removing them when there are fewer requests.
> - Keeps at least one node ready over a period of several minutes, to handle requests even when there are none to handle. The ready state ensures that the service can serve each prediction promptly.
> - Scales down to zero after your model version goes several minutes without a prediction request.

So the inconsistencies in latency you experienced could be because of the slower initial scaling i.e. "cold start". To avoid this, they recommend:

> After the service has scaled down to zero, or when there is a sudden spike in traffic, it can take time (seconds to minutes) to initialize nodes to serve requests. The initialization time depends on your model version size, so a client-side timeout may result in dropping requests until the new nodes have been initialized, and/or increased latencies during this period of time.
>
> To ensure prompt serving at all times, you can specify a minimum number of nodes that the service should keep ready, by setting the `minNodes` option on your model version. This setting can increase cost, as you pay for the nodes even when no predictions are served.

Basically, if you *need* to maintain lower latency, you'll have to keep higher amounts of nodes on hand to serve requests. The tradeoff being that it's much more expensive to do so. In general, most serverless SaaS offerings will follow a similar pricing model.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I will try and set the minNodes. Unfortunately, for the final solution, I do not want to reserve nodes to keep costs down. I have tried sending many requests, one after another, to keep the nodes 'warm' to see if the latency will drop but have had no success. The latency times are always consistent.

Comment: I have now made a version with autoScaling: minNodes: 5 and nothing changed. At this stage, it seems clear to me that a request like this (with many instances) is handled by a single node. I also tried some asyncio requesting but the total time was worse for the whole batch.